# Secure Login credential without using SSL

Tags: asp.net-2.0, ssl-certificate

I am new in SSL, whatever i read and know that its paid digital certificate and after using SSL in website https://  the data transfer is secure at network layer.

In my application i don't have much security concern except loginname and password.

Is there any way to protect Loginname and password without using SSL https://

Comment: Yes, but it's not a good protection. A man-in-the-middle attack could crack this security mechanism easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of authentication schemes which can work securely over plain HTTP. The most common of these is [Digest](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), which is supported by all major web browsers and virtually every web programming framework.

The down-side of using Digest for web sites is that:

- The authentication is handled by the browser itself rather than a login page on the web site, which doesn't look nearly as nice, and doesn't allow you to have all the surrounding helper functions like "forgot your password?" that we've come to expect nowadays.
- If you have no SSL connection, savvy users may feel worried that they are sending their password insecurely (even though they aren't) because they've been trained to look for an SSL connection when entering credentials.

There are other schemes such as [OAuth](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a) which also are safe over plain HTTP, but that is really more for APIs than web sites, so probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Digest isn't exactly secure.  Someone who can see the traffic going between the computers could still intercept the digested password, and mock/modify an HTTP request using the digested password and still gain access to th website.

Comment: Similar issues arise with most other authentication schemes. Token-based authentication such as issuing authentication cookies can also be intercepted and spoofed; the way both are mitigated is to have an expiring token (Digest does this with the nonce). Nothing's truly secure unless all connections are made over SSL (and even then, it isn't truly secure!).

Comment: Ohh i got answer, seems good .

We can generate hash value of password(encrypted)  at client by using MD5 algorith. and for that server has to pass random value key to client when there is request for login page using that key at client side we can encrypt password and send it to server .
As server know the key and therefore can decrypt it.

I think this solution is good. What is your's opinion?

Comment: @Hermant - You can't decrypt MD5 as it is a one-way hash function (though not a very secure one). Unless you have a very good understanding of web authentication mechanisms and cryptography, I would very strongly suggest that you do not try to create your own authentication scheme as it's very, very hard to do correctly.

Comment: ok @Greg, so we should always rely over https:// nothing else. So if someone have website having less secured pages (2-3) but more pages which don't required security, than also should purchase SSL certificates.

Doesn't it looks adtional cost?

Comment: @Hermant - Buying an SSL certificate is what most people end up doing. They're not that expensive really (say US$250/year) which is likely less cash than it would cost in developer time to work out and implement your own mechanism, and probably much less cash than having your users' details exposed when it is cracked. So yeah, I'd probably just send the details in plain-text over SSL.

Comment: @Greg, Can you help me find out free digital certificate (ssl) for website https:// so that i will experiment it. Also i am interested if you can guide me to find out paid one.

Answer (score 2):

There is NO alternative to HTTP security in a browser other than using SSL for every page where the user is logged in. Any other techniques are completely insecure and are nothing but layers of obscurity.

Any homebrew solution over HTTP is always vulnerable to MITM attacks, among other vulnerabilities.

Even with SSL, the login & session mechanism must be secure or it can be cracked using other exploits.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate may be a self signed one. Not necessarily to be a paid one :)

Comment: Sir,
can you give me more details so i can use free digital ceritificate in my website. Also how can i configure it for website

Comment: There is also cacert.org they issue free certificates. They are not trusted by the browsers by default but it is better than self signing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try StartSSL.Org
I am using that currently and it works great even but it somehow the same as cacert.org, they are not trusted by the browsers by default

Answer (score 0):

off the topic, you can obtain your own (self signed) certificate using openssl.

you need to generate a RSA key and a CSR first to generate a self signed cert. On a linux machine with openssl installed:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out mydomain.key 1024

openssl req -new -key mydomain.key -out mydomain.csr   // fill in the details

mv mydomain.key mydomain.key.org

openssl rsa -in mydomain.key.org -out mydomain.key     // creates passphraseless key

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mydomain.csr -signkey mydomain.key -out mydomain.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, hate to open an old thread, but I'm not seeing this as accurate.

I admit that its hard to beat a verifiable certificate, but quite often people use self-signed certificates for test sites.  I'm pretty sure that a simple homebrew solution could be every bit as good as a self-signed certificate.

Heck, I'll even say that with a little presharing of keys (or something like gpg) it could be every bit as secure.

Comment: Could you please supply references backing up your claims? If true, they would be very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd try to make some more 'connective tissue' with these credential concerns.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/808354/iakovos-gurulian had a great answer. 
[store api credential securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636407/store-api-credential-securely)