# store api credential securely

Tags: java, android, security

how can I store API credentials like authentication key, google map API key securely, currently  I have stored that credentials in strings.xml.KeygenratorSpec requires minimum API level of 23 is there any way to store securely any help will be more helpful I am stuck since 2 days but no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do it.

Longer answer: You can use obfuscation in order to make it difficult to find the API credentials, but still, someone with enough time and a few skills will find it and break it. Using KeyGenerator will also not help. I am assuming that you were planning to encrypt/decrypt the API credentials. You will still need a key to be stored in or retrieved by your application. So, the same problem still remains, someone will just have to find one more string before being able to access your credentials.

Obfuscation is probably your best chance. Of course it's not bullet proof, but if it's complicated enough it might delay or demotivate someone who is trying to break your application. You can use proguard to obfuscate your application code (if you don't want to pay for something more advanced), however it will not obfuscate strings. You will have to use other techniques for that. You can find plenty of examples online, and you can use your own layers of obfuscation as well. I don't think that you will find any good recommendations or standards in order to do it. Of course, no matter how hard you try, it will still be a matter of time for someone to revert.

**EDIT:**

This is a good tutorial for configuring proguard: http://wiebe-elsinga.com/blog/obfuscating-for-android-with-proguard/ (be careful what you include because otherwise you might get crashes when you generate an apk)

Regarding string obfuscation, you can use something similar to this: https://github.com/efraespada/AndroidStringObfuscator however you will still need some password, so decryption will be possible. Using an existing string as a password (one that you are already using in your app) might confuse someone if you combine it with code obfuscation. Hiding parts of the string in various files/resources and combining them when you want to create the string will probably add more confusion. However if you make it too complicated it might be easy to spot. For example if your strings.xml contains only 1 encrypted string (unreadable), there is a good chance that this is the string that you are trying to protect. Following this will lead to this information. So, in my opinion, there are no best/good practices. You can get a few ideas by looking online, but I would suggest you judge for yourself where is the best (less obvious) way to hide it, and this depends on your code and application structure. But anyway, this will only trick inexperienced/lazy attackers and automated tools.

Another thing that I do often is to not allow certain parts of the code to run if debugging is enabled, or when the apk file is not signed by myself. These countermeasures are not bullet proof either, but might demotivate a lazy attacker. Here is a good guide on how to do this and other things: https://www.airpair.com/android/posts/adding-tampering-detection-to-your-android-app

Comment: @ jackgu1988 can you please provide any example link if u have